# I can't upload a new wordpress theme from a zipped file

Tags: plugins, themes, upgrade

I'm having trouble trying to upload a zip file Wordpress theme that I bought from Themeforest. I'm getting an inactive "upload theme" button, I have tried to reinstall the Wordpress theme three times now, but I'm having the same problem. I also tried uploaded the theme through FTP to "content" folder, but this did not solve my problem. This started when I upgraded to Wordpress 4.3.1. I'm I missing something here? please advice.

[image]

Comment: The best advice is: ask to the seller for support. There is nothing we can do as we can not know how the theme is coded or zipped.

Comment: Maybe it the MAX_FILE_SIZE in php.ini

Comment: A disabled "Upload Theme" button? Sounds like one of your installed plugin is interfering with WordPress scripts. Does it work when you upload the theme using FTP?

Comment: Thank you Abhik, I have tried uploading the theme through FTP, when I navigate to manage themes I get a page not found

Comment: Could as well be that you ran out of disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, this link explains how to change your filesize upload limit https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04

Basically find your php.ini file, and change these two below to 30M

post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M

Comment: i used this plugin to change wordpress upload file size without access to php ini file https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/upload_max_filesize/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend uninstalling all the other themes from THEMES folder and add the zip file using ftp.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is often due to the fact that the zip not only contains the theme but also the documentation,  readme,  photoshop files, , ...
You should uncompress the zip file and extract only the zip of the theme. This is the file that has to be uploaded in wordpress.